# “Hobby” library stopped working after updating to TeXLive 2014

Tags: tikz-pgf, latex3, hobby

After upgrading to TeXLive 2014 compiling my TikZ pictures prepared with the `hobby` library stopped working.

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby,positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
        scale=1, 
        % circlenodes/.style={circle, draw, font=\footnotesize},
        circlenodes/.style={circle, draw, font=\footnotesize, inner sep=0.1em,
            minimum width=1.5em},
        % midnodes/.style={midway, circle, fill=white, font=\tiny},
        midnodes/.style={midway, font=\tiny, above},
        >=latex,
        ]
        \fill[gray!20](-3, 3) to[curve through={%
            (-2, 1.5) (0,0) (0.5, 0.5) (1, 1.5) (3,3) 
        }] (4, 4) --(4,-0.5) -- (-3, -0.5) -- (-3, 3);
        \draw[thick, ->] (-3,-0.5) -- (4, -0.5) node[at end, anchor=west] {$tgo$};
        \draw[thick, ->] (-3,-0.5) -- (-3, 4) node[at end, anchor=south] {$J(tgo)$};
        \draw[very thick] (-3, 3) to[curve through={%
            (-2, 1.5) (0,0) (0.5, 0.5) (1, 1.5) (3,3) 
        }] (4, 4);
        \node[circlenodes, fill=red!20] (one) at (-3,3) {$a_0$};
        \node[circlenodes, fill=green!20, below=0pt of one] (a1) {$a_1$};
        \node[circlenodes, fill=yellow!20] (five)  at (-2,1.5) {$a_2$};
        \node[circlenodes, fill=blue!20, below=0pt of five] (a3) {$a_3$};
        \node[circlenodes, below=0pt of one] {$a_1$};
        \node[circlenodes, fill=red!20] (three) at (0.5,0.5) {$c_0$};
        \node[circlenodes, fill=green!20, right=0pt of three] (c1) {$c_1$};
        \node[circlenodes, fill=yellow!20, right=0pt of c1] (c2) {$c_2$};
        \node[circlenodes, fill=blue!20, right=0pt of c2] (c3) {$c_3$};
        \node[circlenodes, fill=green!20] (four)  at (3,3) {$b_1$};
        \node[circlenodes, fill=yellow!20, below=0pt of four] (b2) {$b_2$};
        \node[circlenodes, fill=blue!20,] (six)   at (1,1.5) {$b_3$};
        \node[circlenodes, fill=red!20] (two)  at (4,4) {$b_0$};
        \path[->] (two) edge[bend left=30]  node[midnodes] {1} (four);
        \path[->] (b2) edge[bend left=30] node[midnodes] {3} (six);
        \path[->] (a1) edge[bend right=30] node[midnodes] {2} (five);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives the following error message with the `lualatex` compiler:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \fp_if_undefined:NTF 
                     \l_hobby_out_angle_fp {\array_put:Nnx \l_hobby_matrix_b_ar
l.18         }] (4, 4)
                     --(4,-0.5) -- (-3, -0.5) -- (-3, 3);
?
```

With a deadline drawing close, I am getting nervous `:-)`. The wise man might say: ¨Never change a running system.“ I should have listened, but here I am:

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Looks like some things didn't get updated properly. I have it working without any problems on an updated MikTeX.

Comment: If there is not another error in your code, it is most probably connected to either lualatex or you used an earlier version of `hobby` before it was updated (End of january 2014)

Comment: Matter of fact, I kept my TexLive 2013 updated until the freeze a couple of months back. Now I have completely setup TeXLive 2014 anew, so I would be surprised if it was that `:/`. Sorry for forgetting the positioning library.

Comment: I have checked your points. According to `tlmgr` I have Hobby v1.4. Neither compiling with `pdflatex` nor with `lulatex` works.

Comment: Great I now updated and mine is broken too. Haha. It's something to do with the new l3 tools

Comment: see https://github.com/latex3/svn-mirror/blob/master/l3kernel/l3obsolete.txt

Comment: The version on the TeX-SX LaunchPad page contains the fix.  It just needs the documentation updating before being uploaded to CTAN.  Download from http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/files

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is now fixed in the version of [`hobby`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hobby) on CTAN and the change has propagated to TeXLive 14 (I can't say for MikTeX).

If you have an older version, see egreg's post.

Comment: Looks like MikTeX is still at 1.4: http://miktex.org/packages/hobby

Answer (score 16):

The function `\fp_if_undefined:NTF` (and siblings) have been deprecated several months ago and removed from the last revision of the `expl3` suite. Unfortunately, `hobby` wasn't updated timely.

You can momentarily solve the issue by defining in a suitable way the now inexistent functions:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby,positioning}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \fp_if_undefined:NTF \cs_if_free:NTF
\cs_set_eq:NN \fp_if_undefined:NT \cs_if_free:NT
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

After an examination of `hobby.code.tex` they seem the only functions that need to be provided back.

Comment: Better late than never ... it's now fixed on CTAN and in TL14.